# Change rows into columns in R with values yes/no (1/0)

Tags: r

I have one data set (left) and I want to change it into the format (right):
My issue is how to create columns from IDPRODUCT (if it duplicate only create one column) and IDBILL if have values in left table will set 1, else set 0.

[image: view picture]

Please help me solve this case using R. I try some tips using (reshape2, tidyr) but I couldn't done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for your example...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sjmisc)

d <- tibble(
  IDBILL = c(111, 111, 112, 113, 113),
  IDPRODUCT = c("ABC123", "ABC124", "BCH134", "ABC123", "GDF345"),
)

d %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key = IDPRODUCT, value = IDPRODUCT) %>% 
  sjmisc::rec_if(is.character, rec = "NA=0;else=1", append = F) %>% 
  tibble::add_column(IDBILL = unique(d$IDBILL), .before = 1)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   IDBILL ABC123_r ABC124_r BCH134_r GDF345_r
#>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1    111        1        1        0        0
#> 2    112        0        0        1        0
#> 3    113        1        0        0        1
```

Step-by-step:

1) Spread the variable accross columns, but `key` and `value` are identical in this case, because of duplicated values: `tidyr::spread(key = IDPRODUCT, value = IDPRODUCT)` would throw this error: *Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 2), (4, 5)*

```
d %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key = IDPRODUCT, value = IDPRODUCT)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   IDBILL ABC123 ABC124 BCH134 GDF345
#>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1    111 ABC123 ABC124 <NA>   <NA>  
#> 2    112 <NA>   <NA>   BCH134 <NA>  
#> 3    113 ABC123 <NA>   <NA>   GDF345
```

2) Recode `NA` into 0, and all other values (`else`) into 1 - but *only for character vectors* (else, column `IDBILL` would be recoded as well). Note that `rec_if()`, just like e.g. `select_if()`, drops all other columns where `.predicate` does not apply.

```
d %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key = IDPRODUCT, value = IDPRODUCT) %>% 
  sjmisc::rec_if(is.character, rec = "NA=0;else=1", append = F)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   ABC123_r ABC124_r BCH134_r GDF345_r
#>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1        1        1        0        0
#> 2        0        0        1        0
#> 3        1        0        0        1
```

3) ... so we need to add back the ID column:

```
d %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key = IDPRODUCT, value = IDPRODUCT) %>% 
  sjmisc::rec_if(is.character, rec = "NA=0;else=1", append = F) %>% 
  tibble::add_column(IDBILL = unique(d$IDBILL), .before = 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   IDBILL ABC123_r ABC124_r BCH134_r GDF345_r
#>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1    111        1        1        0        0
#> 2    112        0        0        1        0
#> 3    113        1        0        0        1
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
Right_df<- as.data.frame(t(Left_df))
```

Comment: Thank you @King Julien, but my issue is how to create columns from IDPRODUCT (if it duplicate only create one column) and IDBILL if have values in left table will set 1, else set 0. Please help me if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data.table way with dcast

```
library(data.table)

d <- data.table(
  IDBILL = c(111, 111, 112, 113, 113),
  IDPRODUCT = c("ABC123", "ABC124", "BCH134", "ABC123", "GDF345")
)

dcast(d,IDBILL~IDPRODUCT,fill = 0,fun.aggregate = length)

#>    IDBILL ABC123 ABC124 BCH134 GDF345
#> 1:    111      1      1      0      0
#> 2:    112      0      0      1      0
#> 3:    113      1      0      0      1
```